# Allowing the user to edit text already printed on the screen in C

Tags: c, c99

I want to change the text on my screen like a word processor by user input, so can i do gets("text the user can edit", variable to edit by text)

I have tried arrays, and have tried researching dynamically created variables for this. My code is below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) {
int run;
int run = 1;
char string;
do
{
char string = getchar();
} while (run == 1);
}
```

I expect the result to be like a word processor, and allow the user to edit the text already displayed on the screen. The results I have is the program acting like a typewriter for each paragraph, making it unable to be edited after I pressed enter

Comment: That's not the way console output works. If you want it to work like a word processor, write a word processor.

Comment: *"I expect the result to be like a word processor"* - I can assure even console-based simple editors are considerably more complicated than that.

Comment: word processors keep information about location and characteristics of every letter on screen because they put it there as pixels. The only thing you can read from a screen is an array of pixels, unlesss you piggyback on a program which already manages text for you.

Answer (score -1):

Under Linux you can use the readline library and there each line read will be using a system defined line reader, which will allow edits , tossing arrows and such until you press enter. See http://web.mit.edu/gnu/doc/html/rlman_2.html.

In the other hand, if you want to build your own be line editor, or mini word processor, then you will have to keep, at least, the relative position of your current cursor, erase and redraw the line on each meet press, and reposition there caret.

Here is an example of a line editor https://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/136583-line-editor-in-c/